# vue.js vue-grid-layout exchange widgets by drag and drop

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, grid, resize

I use vue.js now for about a month and wanted to use the vue-grid-layout to build up a grid 8x4. Is there a possibility to exchange the widgets by each other or is it only possible to put it in between and push it to the bottom?

Example by dragging c to a:

```
a  b  c  d
gets
c  b     d
a
```

But what I want to achieve is:

```
a  b  c  d
gets
c  b  a  d
```

What is the best way to implement such a behavior?
Do I have to use a different grid engine?
if so, which one would you prefer?

Thx in advance
Pedy

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this effect, you are going to have to orchestrate several events on several components, and signal from the children to the parent when certian things happen.

We have 2 components involved in this operation - the parent component and the draggable child component (which has multiple instances).  In the parents template we have the following...

```
<div id="dropTargetDiv" @drop.prevent="drop" v-on:startIndex="setStartIndex(value)" v-on:targetIndex="setTargetIndex(value)">
    <draggable-component v-for="(itemData, index) in dataArray" :itemData="itemData" index="index"/>
</div>
```

The parent also has these methods...

```
setStartIndex(value) {
   this.startIndex = value;
},
setTargetIndex(value) {
     this.targetIndex = value;
},
drop(event) {

    this.swapElements(this.startIndex, this.targetIndex);                       
},
swapElements(start, target) {

    // Clone the original array
    var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataArray));

    // Swap elements
    var startElement = newArray[start];
    var targetElement = newArray[target];

    newArray[target] = startElement;
    newArray[start] = targetElement;

    // Update the UI
    this.dataArray = newArray;
}
```

In the child component, on its root element, we have the following...

```
<div class="draggableItem" draggable="true" @dragstart="$emit('startIndex', this.index)" @dragenter.prevent="$emit('targetIndex', this.index)">
```

If you see that the target index isn't being set correctly, you may want to replace the @dragenter.prevent with @dragover.prevent.

This should work - comments are welcome.  You will need to drop on top of another child, not between them.

Comment: Hey Rodney, thanks for the quick answer. I get the same index for drag and drop and the grid item is still moving down. Do you know which event controls the move of it.